# How do I prevent 'require' module cache executions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, knex.js

I've been reading around, and from what I understand, `require` automagically executes and parses the functions in the module.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

The use-case is simple; to prevent myself from having a 50000902931 long line file, I want to move MySql functions to a separate module (say, `db_functions`).

But if `require` automatically runs all of these functions on start up, and *again* when I call the function in `app.js`, database information will be incredibly redundant. Here's a quick and easy example snippet:

```
app.js

const express = require('express')
const db_functions = require('./db_functions')

app.get(/save_a_new_visit', (req, res, next) => {
   db_functions.saveAVisit
     .then(() => {
        res.sendStatus(200)
     }
});
```

And

```
db_functions.js

const knex = require('knex')

function saveAVisit(knex) {
    console.log('You are saving a new visit')

    const visit = {
       visits: new Date()
    }

    return knex('this_is_an_example').insert(visit)
}
```

When I run my server, my console is logging `You are saving a new visit` on startup, and then will do so *again* when I visit the `/save_a_new_visit` endpoint.

Of course, I'd like it only to create a new visit when I visit the visiting page. Right? Logical, I think.

And here's a second curve ball - is this only happening because I am developing locally? Once the project is placed in Heroku or wherever, will this double writing stop? Any help, tips, or notes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing that I am wondering is what is the behavior that you are currently seeing from your app? The only thing that `require` does is resolve all `require` references all the way down to the bottom of every module so that initial versions of all referenced modules are loaded once and only once. Individual functions defined within any given module are not executed until the application logic executes those functions. So I am wondering if you are seeing some strange behavior, or are just concerned about something happening based on your research.

Comment: I suppose I am seeing strange behavior - referenced modules are loaded and also *executed* when they are loaded. I wasn’t sure if this was ‘strange’ behavior or not (I’m fairly new to Node.js, so I thought this was just how things went). When I start my server, all of my exported functions are being run - as soon as I start the server. Then when I navigate to a particular webpage, the function is run again. The function running in application call works, but the function also seems to run on simple application boot-up.

Comment: you are not exporting anything on `db_functions.js`

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot to add that line. I’ll edit it in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a few changes to your code as follows:

```
app.js

const app = require('express')
const db_functions = require('./db_functions')

app.get('/save_a_new_visit', (req, res, next) => {
    db_functions.saveAVisit()
      .then(() => {
          res.sendStatus(200)
          next()
      })
})
```

and

```
db_functions.js

const knex = require('knex')

module.exports.saveAVisit = async () => {
    console.log('You are saving a new visit')

    const visit = { visits: new Date() }

    return await knew('this_is_an_example').insert(visit)
}
```

In the `app.js` code, I changed the name of your Express module import variable to align with your declaration of the RESTful route below those import statements. Also, I added a method invocation to your promise chain calling the `saveAVisit()` function. I did not specify any parameters to this function because in reality you do not need any defined in that function, as you can see in the second code snippet. Finally, I added a call to the `next()` function since you included it in your parameters list for the route definition and if you are paying attention to the passage of the `next()` function you should make sure that you call it.

In your `db_functions.js` code, I changed your function definition to include a prefix so that the function is actually available to any importing code that attempts to import this module. Second, I defined the function as being asynchronous using the `async` keyword. I do this so that you can use the `await` keyword when you define your actual database interface logic in the body of the function. Please checkout the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) documentation for more information and examples on using these two special keywords. I also removed your defined function parameter because it is not necessary to pass an instance of the `knex` module when you are already importing it at the top of the module definition. Finally, because I am assuming that the `knex.insert()` function is asynchronous, I added an `await` keyword before that call so that the code waits for the response from the database before returning to the executing function.

Making these several changes to your code should result in your database code no longer being called on module import. If the problem still persists after making these changes, maybe there is additional code in your application that you did not provide above that is resulting in this behavior. If so, please edit your post and add that code as well so that I can assist you with fixing it.